# Extended IdentityUser not saving

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

Allright! So I extended my IdentityUser but it is not saving my Users anymore. The code samples can be viewed below. I am trying to seed my database with an admin user but it is not being stored. I have tried running a debugger on my seeds, but it doesn't trigger on anything. So I'm kinda lost. So, here is the code.

My extended User Class:

```
public class User : IdentityUser, IBaseEntity
{
    public virtual ICollection<TimeLogEntry> TimeLogEntries { get; set; } 

    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
    public DateTime UpdatedAt { get; set; }

    public bool IsRemoved { get; set; }

    public virtual User CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public virtual User UpdatedBy { get; set; } 

    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<User> manager, string authenticationType)
    {
        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, authenticationType);
        // Add custom user claims here
        return userIdentity;
    }
}
```

Then ofcourse the Context that inherits from the IdentityDbContext:

```
public class Context : IdentityDbContext<User>, IContext
{
    public Context()
        : base("MyConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
        Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
    }

    // DBSETS

    public static Context Create() => new Context();

   // MODELBUILDER
}
```

and finaly my seed:

```
protected override void Seed(Context context)
    {
        // Launch debugger on seeds
        //if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached == false)
        //    System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();

        SeedUsers(context);;
    }

    private void SeedUsers(Context context)
    {
        var manager = new UserManager<User>(new UserStore<User>(context));

        var adminUser = new User
        {
            UserName = "Admin",
            Email = "admin@test.com"
        };

        if (!manager.Users.Any())
        {
            manager.Create(adminUser, "Admin");
        }
    }
```

I hope someone can help me with this!

Answer (score 0):

The Seed() that is inside your initializer will only run when your database is recreated - for instance when you are using DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges.

If you use migrations (MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion initializer), there is another Seed() that runs every time you apply the migration using `update-database`.

http://blog.oneunicorn.com/2013/05/28/database-initializer-and-migrations-seed-methods/